# Who is Jachislaz Osnos?

Tags: training

I was reading this article on Gata Kamsky, and I came across the name [Jachislaz Osnos](https://www.nytimes.com/1990/05/13/magazine/a-father-s-pawn.html).

The article states he was Korchnoi's trainer. Does anyone have any further information on him?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vyacheslav_Osnos